# To read 'n' lines from a file and iterate using Shell Script

Tags: shell, batch-processing

I have a Employee File with 300 Lines in it. Right now im reading all the lines in it and calling a subprocess to process .But i need to read 20 lines at a Time and call a SubProcess for it and iterate untill it finishes all 300 lines?

```
while read -r name age empno ; do
    echo $EmpName $EmpAge $EmpNumber
    ./run.sh RUN_EMP -a $EmpName -b $EmpAge -c $EmpNumber &  
   done < "$File_Employee" >  /logs/Emp_`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`.log
   wait
```

is there an option in Shell Scripting to limit the number of lines to read?

In case if i need to run 20 process at any given time;Is my below approach fine? when i try to execute this the process runs for first 20 jobs and exists gracefully.

```
    while read -r empname empage empnumber ; do
    echo $empname $empage $empnumber
        while [[ $( jobs | wc -l ) -ge 20 ]]
      do
        echo going to sleep now at $(date)
        sleep 3
          done
    ./run.sh RUN_EMP -a $empname -b $empage -c $empnumber &
      done <"$File_Employee" >Emp_`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`.log
wait
```

Comment: How will you pass 20 lines to `run.sh`?

Comment: Right now i pass the entire file as an input to the run.sh so i have 300 subprocess running at the background.
i was thinking if i can have some level of filter ; so that it can split and read the file per 20 lines or any custom value and call the subprocess.

Comment: Use `split` to split input file on 20 lines each and then call your sub process for each split sub-file.

Comment: @Ragav What would the command line for `./run.sh` look like if you were passing it 20 lines to run at once? Or, is it your intention to run 20 processes of `./run.sh` and then wait for them to complete before starting 20 more?

Comment: @John1024 my intention is to run first 20 processes of run.sh - (basically the this script has been designed in such a way that it can run in parallel batches) i will wait for them to complete and then start with the next 20 untill all lines in my Employee File are read.

Answer (score 2):

This `bash` script counts the number of `./run.sh` processes created and every 20th, it stops and waits for them to complete before starting more:

```
#!/bin/bash
count=0
while read -r empname empage empnumber ; do
    echo $empname $empage $empnumber
    ./run.sh RUN_EMP -a $empname -b $empage -c $empnumber &
    ((++count % 20 == 0 )) && wait
done <"$File_Employee" >/logs/Emp_`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`.log
```

The key change here is this line:

```
((++count % 20 == 0 )) && wait
```

This line increments the count by 1 and then checks to see if `count` is a multiple of 20.  If it is, it calls the `bash` builtin `wait` which waits for background processes to complete.

#### POSIX

The following should work on any POSIX shell:

```
File_Employee=employees
count=0
while read -r empname empage empnumber ; do
    echo $empname $empage $empnumber
    ./run.sh RUN_EMP -a $empname -b $empage -c $empnumber &
    count=$((count+1))
    [ 0 -eq $((count % 20)) ] && wait
done <"$File_Employee" >Emp_`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`.log
```

Comment: When i tried it processed first 20 lines and then it exit gracefully. 
btw im using sh for my process.

Comment: @Ragav "im using sh for my process." Please clarify.  It shouldn't matter if `run.sh` uses `sh` instead of `bash` but the arithmetic  in my added line requires `bash`.  What operating system and what version of `sh` are you using?

Comment: @johh version of regular Bourne Shell - /usr/bin/sh OS is Linux

Comment: @Ragav I just updated the answer with a version that should work on any basic POSIX-compliant shell.  No modern linux system uses a 'regular Bourne Shell' any more.  They are all striving at least for POSIX-compliance.  If you are on a Debian-like system (that includes Ubuntu), for example, the `/bin/sh` is the `dash` shell.  The above script will work under `dash`.

Comment: im exploring an option to always run 20 Process at any given time. in case if my first process completes i will start the next process. So that i can make use of the Parallelism. pl let me know if this the correct way; Updated the code to my Question.

Comment: @Ragav I didn't test it but it looks right to me.  Nice work!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
end=0
while [ $end -eq 0 ]; do
    for (( i=0 ; $i < 20 ; i++ )) do
        read -r name age empno || {
            end=1
            break
        }
        # do something with it
    done
    # do something with the group
done
```

There are other, similar forms.  Do note that you probably need to be prepared for the possibility that the input doesn't divide evenly into groups of 20 lines.  The example code handles that as far as it can do, but the "do something" parts may need their own accommodation.